# How to hide mouse cursor with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide, mouse-cursor

How to hide mouse cursor with jquery in entire webpage.
 I tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(body).css({
           'cursor' : 'none'
        });
});
```

But this is not working in all the browsers. Is there any plugin to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you give single quotes for body in your original code??

Comment: @gov : Here i forgot to give single quotes but, but i gave in my project.

Comment: By above code ..firefox only supporting..

Comment: you aren't supposed to have single quotes around cursor

Answer (score 4):

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'none');
```

Comment: The quotes surrounding 'body' are important.

Comment: Also, this will not work when hovering over Flash movies -- that will need to be taken care of in the movie itself. Additionally, this will not work for elements that explicitly name the cursor in their CSS. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066

Answer (score 2):

I bet it has nothing to do with the jQuery method, but in fact the CSS for your page.

Make sure (using firebug) that the body element is actually visible on the page, the contents might because the overflow is set to auto by default, but you'll also need to set the body height and width to 100% to ensure that when you're mouse moves across the screen it actually invokes body.mouseover()

Here's a working example » http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/XQmqe/

Comment: @ILMV : Google chrome is not supporting this ...in chrome cursor is visible ...even in your working example..

Comment: That's funny, it was working for me... and I'm using Google Chrome. I'm having problems with jsFiddle at the moment, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I am usign Google chrome 8.0.552.215 beta

Comment: I'm using the exact same release on Ubuntu 10.04 and it works perfectly for me :S

Comment: i am using it on windows and i don't think it is related to OS

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be done by loading custom transparent ICO/PNG file as cursor.

```
cursor: url('my-transparent-cursor.ico');
```

So now user has cursor but is transparent, invisible. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a transparent div overlay (div with an absolute position, 100% width and height, and positive z-index) with cursor set to none. Then use jQuery to toggle it on/off?

Comment: It might be an idea to make the position `fixed` instead of `absolute`, depending on the structure of the document.

Comment: @Victor, that may be an idea. The only hiccup in my plan is if the page is longer than the window they can scroll out of the clear div. remove overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Should definitely work in all browsers. Check in firebug which elements the cursor occurs on and see if it has an explicit "cursor: pointer;" or equivalent setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can make overlay with div element when page is ready you set visibility to block.

HTML CODE:

```
<div>Test</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: none;
  visibility: block;
}
```

hope it can help u..
I test it on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) and it works for me

Maybe it what u find

Comment: @killerfish: I'm not test it on Chrome, but i use div not body... Why it doesn't work..